# Компилятор выдаёт следующие ошибки: C2760 и C1903; Первая ошибка на строках - 17, 69, 20, 49; Последняя на 17 и 1 строке;

Tags: c++, windows, ооп

Ошибки:

1>D:\Projects\Engine\Titan\Titan\Source.cpp(17,69): error C2760: синтаксическая ошибка: непредвиденный токен ";"; требуется "{"
1>D:\Projects\Engine\Titan\Titan\Source.cpp(26): message : выполняется компиляция ссылки на экземпляр класс шаблон функции "plane_metric::plane"
1>D:\Projects\Engine\Titan\Titan\Source.cpp(20,49): error C2760: синтаксическая ошибка: непредвиденный токен ";"; требуется "{"
1>D:\Projects\Engine\Titan\Titan\Source.cpp(17,1): fatal error C1903: не удается восстановить после предыдущих ошибок; остановка компиляции

```
#include < iostream>

namespace plane_metric 
{
    template<typename Field>
    class plane 
    {
    private:
        Field** field   = nullptr;  // Field Buffer
        int str         = 0;        // Strings Count
        int coll        = 0;        // Collums Count

        void clear(Field def);      // Filling field buffer default value
    public:
        /* Constructors */
        plane(const int str, const int coll);
        plane(const int str, const int coll, Field def) : plane(str, coll);

        plane(Field** field);
        plane(Field** field, Field def) : plane(field);

        /* Main Funclional */

        void fill(Field ch);

    };
}

int main() {
    //std::cout << "Hello, world !" << std::endl;

    plane_metric::plane<char> obj(10, 10, '?');

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

template<typename Field>
void plane_metric::plane<Field>::clear(Field def)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->str; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < this->coll; j++) {
            this->field[i][j] = def;
        }
    }
}

template<typename Field>
plane_metric::plane<Field>::plane(const int str, const int coll)
{
    this->str   = str;
    this->coll  = coll;

    this->field = new Field * [this->str];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->str; i++) {
        field[i] = new Field[this->coll];
    }
}

template<typename Field>
plane_metric::plane<Field>::plane(const int str, const int coll, Field def)
{
    clear(def);
}

template<typename Field>
plane_metric::plane<Field>::plane(Field** field)
{
    this->field = field;
}

template<typename Field>
plane_metric::plane<Field>::plane(Field** field, Field def)
{
    clear(def);
}

template<typename Field>
void plane_metric::plane<Field>::fill(Field ch)
{
    clear(ch);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вы собираетесь использовать делегирование конструкторов - используйте. Но это тем не менее не избавляет вас от необходимости предоставлять тело для конструктора, пусть даже и пустое

```
plane(const int str, const int coll, Field def) : plane(str, coll)
  {}
```

---

Однако дальше по коду вы вдруг снова предоставляете определение для того же самого конструктора. Что это за чушь? Определение должно быть одно. Соберите все в одно место.

Либо в определении класса оставьте только объявление конструктора

```
plane(const int str, const int coll, Field def);
```

а все остальное поместите в определение конструктора за пределами класса

```
template<typename Field>
plane_metric::plane<Field>::plane(const int str, const int coll, Field def) : plane(str, coll)
{
  clear(def);
}
```

Либо все перенесите в определение класса. Либо туда, либо туда.

Comment: Этого не дрстаточно, нужно определять функцию clear.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: В смысле? Я вижу в коде определение `clear`.

Comment: Да, я  не заметил просто. Просто название не подходит к коду, так и запутаться не трудно...